# Using python and yahoo finance (so something else) how can I get data for the price of an an asset throughout a trading day for X number of days

Tags: python, finance, yahoo, trading, stocks

I don't really have sample code other than the library that I should be using is probably pandas? I am pretty new to both python and yahoo.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a very broad question, probably too broad for this site. Your best bet is to google what you're trying to do, check some tutorials, then try some things and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad, but you can do something like this (if I am understanding correctly):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as data
import datetime as dt 

start = dt.datetime(2018,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)

df = data.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', start, end)
```